Gunicorn App Isn't Working With GAE (static files work but making a request to the script results in a 503 error code)
The static files work fine but for some reason the entrypoint isn't running at all. I've even tried making running start.sh as an entrypoint with an echo "Starting gunicorn" and I don't see it in the logs. It's not my code I'm pretty sure since I've tested locally. This worked before when I didn't use gunicorn.
app.yaml:
runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -t 4 -w 1 --timeout 120 main:app -b :$PORT

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

network:
  session_affinity: true

handlers:
  # API handlers
  - url: /api/.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  # Static file handlers
  - url: /(.*\.(html|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|json|webp|svg))
    static_files: frontend/dist/\1
    upload: frontend/dist/(.*\.(html|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|json|webp|svg))
    secure: always

  # Catch-all handler for other static files and single-page app support
  - url: /.*
    static_files: frontend/dist/index.html
    upload: frontend/dist/index.html
    secure: always

I was expecting the API/script and the static frontend to work but for some reason only the static files are working.
SOLVED:
I found out that there was something wrong with the route handling and I started hosting the static files on Python. Since it was an SPA my handler looked like this:
# Catch-all for SPA
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    if re.match("(.*\.(html|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|json|webp|svg))", path):
        return app.send_static_file(path)
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")


What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error? You should also include code that loads one of the paths that you say isn't working

The error is that when the frontend tries making a call to the /api it gets a 503 error.

503 is saying your service isn't available. Did you add gunicorn to your requirements.txt file? Once you include an entrypoint in your app.yaml file, you need to include the corresponding package in your requirements.txt file

yeah, I did. I don't see any gunicorn logs or errors which is strange too. It's like it just doesn't run at all even though it says: "build": Using config appstart.Config{Runtime:"python39", Entrypoint:appstart.Entrypoint{Type:"User", Command:"gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -t 4 -w 1 --timeout 120 main:app -b :$PORT", WorkDir:""}, MainExecutable:""}

Try a basic entrypoint - gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app and for your api home url, return a basic string like "hello world" and see if it works

not even that works
Edit: actually I tried
handlers:
API handlers

url: /.*
script: auto
secure: always
redirect_http_response_code: 301
and it worked. I'm going to investigate.


SOLVED: I found out that there was something wrong with the route handling and I started hosting the static files on Python. Since it was an SPA my handler looked like this:
# Catch-all for SPA
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    if re.match("(.*\.(html|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|json|webp|svg))", path):
        return app.send_static_file(path)
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
``
Thanks to NoCommandLine for helping me out.

